# Windows 7 complains that Nexus S driver is missing

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, windows

When I connected my Nexus S to my PC running Windows 7 Professional (32-bit) via USB cable, the system installed a handful of drivers before complaining that the Nexus S driver wasn't installed.

I can see the USB storage as a drive letter. And I can use MyPhoneExplorer to browse all of the memory.

I'm just concerned that if I go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers, the Nexus S icon is there with a warning symbol on it because the driver wasn't loaded.

If I try to let Windows fix the problem, it searches and fails to find the driver and suggests I take it up with the manufacturer.

If I select Properties for the Nexus S, I see the drive letter listed plus "USB Composite Device" and "USB Mass Storage Device", but sitting at the top of the list is "Nexus S" with a warning sign.

Should I be worried? Does anyone else have this?

I have previously had a different Android phone connected and that was OK once I got the drivers for that...

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem among Android phones. Sometimes Windows might try to install drivers for your phone which might not necessarily be complete.

Like Matthew said in the answer above me, you could use the Android SDK package which usually includes drivers for Nexus devices but in the event it doesn't work:

You need to get the usb drivers from the manufacturer. Following the instructions in this link might help:

http://nexusshacks.com/nexus-s-hacks/how-to-install-nexus-s-windows-usb-drivers/

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no reason to be worried.  You can install the drivers from the Android SDK and that should fix the issue, though.

Comment: How exactly would one install drivers from Android SDK? Can you please elaborate?